# How to add multiple image using react native image picker

Tags: react-native

I am building a simple social media Application. The User can add status, location, video from youtube, and photos. But I had a problem uploading multiple images using react native image picker. I have read the documentation but I don't know how to fix the problem

Here's my function code

```
onPhotoPress() {
 const options = {
  quality: 1.0,
  maxWidth: 50,
  maxHeight: 50,
  storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
  },
};
ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, openPicker(), (response) => {
  console.log('Response = ', response);

  if (response.didCancel) {
    console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
  }
  else if (response.error) {
    console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
  }
  else if (response.customButton) {
    console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
  }
  else {
    const source = { uri: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${response.data}` };

    this.setState({
      avatarSource: source,
      name: response.fileName,
      data: response.data,
      type: response.type,
      path: response.uri,
    });
  }
 });
}
```

This my code for view images

```
         {this.state.avatarSource !== null ?
          <Image
            source={this.state.avatarSource}
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              resizeMode: 'contain',
              marginVertical: 12,
            }}
          /> : <View /> }
```

This is picture for upload single image 
[image]

so Can you help me, to get multiple image or give me advice another library i should use to solve my problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This library started as a basic bridge of the native iOS image picker, and I want to keep it that way. As such, functionality beyond what the native UIImagePickerController supports will not be supported here. **Multiple image selection**, more control over the crop tool, and landscape support are things missing from the native iOS functionality - not issues with my library. If you need these things, react-native-image-crop-picker might be a better choice for you.

As you can see in the [React Native Image Picker](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker) README, you can't do multiple images selection using this module. You better try to use [React Native Image Crop Picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker) to do that.

Comment: Expo is not supported :-/

Comment: maxFile feature not supported by Android

Answer (score 3):

```
100% Sure this is working

use the library for multiple images selection and upload 
react-native-image-crop-picker

import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';


  takePics = () => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 200,
      height: 200, compressImageMaxHeight: 400,
      compressImageMaxWidth: 400, cropping: true, multiple: true
    })
      .then(response => {
        let tempArray = []
        console.log("responseimage-------" + response)
        this.setState({ ImageSource: response })
        console.log("responseimagearray" + this.state.ImageSource)
        response.forEach((item) => {
          let image = {
            uri: item.path,
            // width: item.width,
            // height: item.height,
          }
          console.log("imagpath==========" + image)
          tempArray.push(image)
          this.setState({ ImageSourceviewarray: tempArray })
          // console.log('savedimageuri====='+item.path);

          console.log("imagpath==========" + image)
        })

      })

  }
```

Comment: How to open the camera here?

Comment: takePics = () => {
    ImagePicker.openCamera({
      width: 200,
      height: 200, compressImageMaxHeight: 400,
      compressImageMaxWidth: 400, cropping: true, multiple: true
    })

Comment: maxFile feature not supported by Android

Answer (score 3):

Under the options for choose file add selectionLimit: 5 here is the code.

```
  var imgArray = [];
  const [filePath, setFilePath] = useState([]);
  const [filePathArray, setFilePathArray] = useState([]);
const chooseFile = (type) => {
let options = 
{
      mediaType: type,
      maxWidth: 300,
      maxHeight: 550,
      quality: 1,
      selectionLimit: 5
};
    launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {

     response.assets.forEach(function (item, index) {

        console.log(item);
        if(item[index] !=null)
        {
          imgArray.push(item[0].uri);
          setFilePathArray(filePathArray => [...filePathArray, imgArray]);
        }

      });
      ///Loop through responses
      setFilePath(response.assets[0]);

    });
  };
```

And On the view

```
      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={0.5}
        style={styles.buttonStyle}
        onPress={() => chooseFile('photo')}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Choose Image</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 2):

use this for the multiple allowsMultipleSelection: true,

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to add multiple images either try multi-picker or make recursive calls on response after image is selected in this module. Show a popup to user to add more images and add all images to a list.

Comment: what is `multi-picker`?

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved using react-native-multiple-image-picker

```
yarn add @ko-developerhong/react-native-multiple-image-picker
```

Answer (score 0):

if you observe the below code    **selectionLimit:10** like this you can select maltipel images no need of install any alternative plug in.

```
export const handleChooseFromGallery = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      launchImageLibrary({
          mediaType: 'photo',
          includeBase64: false,
          maxHeight: 200,
          maxWidth: 200,
          selectionLimit:10
      }, response => {
          if (response.didCancel) {
              console.log('User cancelled image picker');
          } else if (response.error) {
              console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
          } else {
              resolve(response);
          }
      });
  });
};
```