# How can we click and upload multiple images in react native,i have used image picker,image crop picker,but not able to do it

Tags: reactjs, react-native, picker

Not able to click and upload multiple images using react native image picker and crop image picker,using image picker.open camera , adding multiple:true,
But nothing working can anyone one ping me with an example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add multiple image using react native image picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45543706/how-to-add-multiple-image-using-react-native-image-picker)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "react-native-image-picker" to pick multiple images. If you read the "README" of this library, you will see "selectionLimit" option of lauchImageLibrary function, with the description:

> Default is 1, use 0 to allow any number of files. Only iOS version >= 14 & Android version >= 13 support 0 and also it supports providing any integer value

So, just set { "selectionLimit" : 0 }